# Rails Includes not returning all child records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the following query which grabs `Orders` that have `Addresses` where the state is `Texas`.

```
orders = Order.includes(:addresses).where(:addresses => {state: "Texas"})
```

I am able to get all of my orders, but I noticed while accessing the addresses that not all of the addresses were stored in memory.

Here is how I found the issue:

```
orders.each do |i|
    puts orders.addresses.length #outputs 1 or 2 randomly
    puts orders.addresses.count #outputs 2 every time
end
```

All of my orders have two addresses; one billing and one shipping. Printing `length` would show only `1` for about half the records and would show `2` for the other half. Printing `count` always showed `2`. If I changed the query from includes to joins, it worked correctly but would not "include" addresses in the query.

UPDATE

Changing `includes` to `joins` in the query above causes everything to work as expected. However, I lose the preloading. I don't understand why includes is not working here. Something seems wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
orders.each do |i|
  puts i.addresses.length 
  puts i.addresses.count 
end
```